# How to use BeautifulSoup to search for a list of tags, with one item in the list having an attribute?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Does anyone know how to use bs4 in python to search for multiple tags, one of which will need an attribute?

For example, to search for all occurrences of one tag with an attribute, I know I can do this:

`tr_list = soup_object.find_all('tr', id=True)`

And I know I can also do this:

`tag_list = soup_object.find_all(['a', 'b', 'p', 'li'])`

But I can not figure out how to combine the two statements, which in theory would give me a list, in order of occurrence of all of those html tags, with each 'tr' tag having an id.

html snippet would be something like below:

```
  <tr id="uniqueID">
   <td nowrap="" valign="baseline" width="8%">
    <b>
     A_time_as_text
    </b>
   </td>
   <td class="storyTitle">
    <a href="a_link.com" target="_new">
     some_text
    </a>
    <b>
     a_headline_as_text
    </b>
    a_number_as_text
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <br/>
   </td>
   <td class="st-Art">
    <ul>
     <li>
      more_text_text_text
      <strong>
       more_text_text_text
       <font color="228822">
        more_text_text_text
       </font>
      </strong>
      more_text_text_text
     </li>
     <li>
      more_text_text_text
      <ul>
       <li>
        more_text_text_text
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
```

Thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: could you give an example of the html you are trying to scrape? thanks

Comment: Sure, it is a protected site and I don't want any trouble so I've put in some obvious placeholders in the text:

Comment: <tr id="uniqueID">
<td nowrap="" valign="baseline" width="8%">
<b>
A_time_as_text
</b>
</td>
<td class="storyTitle">
<a href="a_link.com" target="_new">
some_text
</a>
<b>
a_headline_as_text
</b>
a_number_as_text
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<br/>
</td>
<td class="st-Art">
<ul>
<li>
more_text_text_text
<strong>
more_text_text_text
<font color="228822">
more_text_text_text
</font>
</strong>
more_text_text_text
</li>
<li>
more_text_text_text
<ul>
<li>
more_text_text_text
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

Comment: I'd use a lambda

Comment: @SammyDoodle, it'll better if you add the html in the question in a formatted manner.

Comment: If you consider the above html, what output your to-be scraper should populate? Are you after all the texts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you add `tr` to the required list of tags and then check for the presence of the `id` attribute within the loop:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all(['a', 'b', 'p', 'li', 'tr']):
    if tag.name != 'tr' or (tag.name == 'tr' and tag.get('id')):
        print tag.name
```

For your html, this would display:

```
tr
b
a
b
li
li
li
```

---

Note, if you are actually trying to get `a` `b` `p` and `li` tags that are inside a `tr` with an `id` present, then the following approach would be more suitable:

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr', id=True):
    for tag in tr.find_all(['a', 'b', 'p', 'li']):
        print tag.name, tag.get_text(strip=True)
```

This would give you:

```
b A_time_as_text
a some_text
b a_headline_as_text
```